# Garbage Collector slowing down the application when iterating the arraylist

Tags: android

I use the following code to convert elements from ArrayList to string:

```
public static List<Location> GPSLocalLocations = new ArrayList<Location>(1);
String mystr = "";
for (int i=0; i<GPSService.GPSLocalLocations.size(); i++)
{
mystr += "\n" + GPSService.GPSLocalLocations.get(i).toString();
}
```

Changed my code to the following:

```
for (int i=0; i<GPSService.GPSLocalLocations.size(); i++)
{
    gpslog.append("\n").append(GPSService.GPSLocalLocations.get(i).toString());
}
```

It causes less GC Free messages :). My mistake, application didn't hang because of that... I think because I ran a my ASyncTask multiple times...

But still iterating ArrayList of more than 1000 elements takes some time [about 10 seconds]. Is that ok?

Comment: Where in the `AsyncTask` does this code run? Post all of the code for your `AsyncTask`

Comment: Code runs in the doInBackground method, so it is like a different thread. During this code the LogCat keeps showing: GC freed messages for about minute. When I remove these lines of code everything work perfect :P.

Comment: I have an app which imports thousands of rows into a SQL database and the GC freed messages show in logcat for all of those...it doesn't 'hang' the app. What's your actual problem? What do you mean by "my application hangs"?

Comment: "...iterating ArrayList of more than 1000 elements takes some time [about 10 seconds]. Is that ok?" - As long as you provide meaningful feedback to the user to let them know what is going on, 10 seconds is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to use [StringBuilder](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).

From here http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/location/Location.java#Location.toString%28%29 :

```
@Override public String  [More ...] toString() {
    return "Location[mProvider=" + mProvider +
        ",mTime=" + mTime +
        ",mLatitude=" + mLatitude +
        ",mLongitude=" + mLongitude +
        ",mHasAltitude=" + mHasAltitude +
        ",mAltitude=" + mAltitude +
        ",mHasSpeed=" + mHasSpeed +
        ",mSpeed=" + mSpeed +
        ",mHasBearing=" + mHasBearing +
        ",mBearing=" + mBearing +
        ",mHasAccuracy=" + mHasAccuracy +
        ",mAccuracy=" + mAccuracy +
        ",mExtras=" + mExtras + "]";
}
```

I'd recommend write it yourself in following way:

```
public static List<Location> GPSLocalLocations = new ArrayList<Location>(1);
StringBuilder gpslog = new StringBuilder();
for (int i=0; i<GPSService.GPSLocalLocations.size(); i++)
{
    Location location = GPSService.GPSLocalLocations.get(i); 
    gpslog.append("\n")
        .append("Location[Provider=").append(location.getProvider(())())
        .append(",Time=").append(location.getTime())
        .append(",Latitude=").append(location.getLatitude())
        .append(",Longitude=").append(location.getLongitude())
        .append(",HasAltitude=").append(location.getHasAltitude())
        .append(",Altitude=").append(location.getAltitude())
        .append(",HasSpeed=").append(location.getHasSpeed())
        .append(",Speed=").append(location.getSpeed())
        .append(",HasBearing=").append(location.getHasBearing())
        .append(",Bearing=").append(location.getBearing())
        .append(",HasAccuracy=").append(location.getHasAccuracy())
        .append(",Accuracy=").append(location.getAccuracy())
        .append(",Extras=").append(location.getExtras()).append("]");
}
```

Comment: I did the following: StringBuilder mystr = new StringBuilder(""); for (int i=0; i<GPSService.GPSLocalLocations.size(); i++) {
mystr.append("\n").append(GPSService.GPSLocalLocations.get(i)).toString();} But GC still shows the messages :/.

Comment: post code as an edit to your question. Code in comments is jumbled to the point of near uselessness...

Comment: Its because toString method of Location creates new String object that being read in append method and than its being removed by GC. If you want to do it without creating new object you could try to use getLatitude and getLongitude methods.